# What was the first programming language with Enumerations?

Tags: c, swift, enums, enumeration

I'm reading about Swift `enum`'s in the [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html) guide and the text was comparing the differences between Swift's `enum` and C's `enum`. This made me curious as to where enumerations came from originally. I did search online before asking and even asked a few people and they *assumed* C. (I suppose I'm trying to confirm if enumerations came from C originally.)

**Question**

What was the first programming language to include enumerations?

Comment: Pascal had enumerated types, but didn't use the keyword `enum`.  Does that count?  AFAIK, the keyword `enum` was first used by C, but the concept is older by quite a margin.

Comment: If the intended purpose behind Pascals enum-like feature was to serve the same purpose as an enum I would say, yes? (I don't know)

Comment: It was — see Wikipedia on [Enumerated type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type).  I think it is the oldest of the languages listed there, where the LISP referred to is Common Lisp, which postdates Pascal even though original LISP handily pre-dates Pascal.

Comment: Since this is a history question of no *practical* use to programmers, it's probably off-topic here. It's being [discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307595/what-should-i-do-with-this-history-question#307595) and will probably get closed when the crowd from Meta descends on it. It's a good, clear and answerable question unlike much of the dross that gets asked here, and I'm certainly not going to spend one of *my* close votes on it, but it's outside the scope of what this particular SE site is supposed to be for (in my opinion).

Comment: @MarkAmery Should I delete the question? If so is beta a better place to ask or is there yet a more preferred place?

Comment: @DanBeaulieu I don't think there is any site on the SE network where this would be on topic, sadly. No need to delete (although you could do so if you wished) - the community will close it if they don't think it belongs.

Comment: @MarkAmery Fair enough, I suppose I have my answer thanks to Johnathan Leffler

Comment: this is a 'some what' opinion based question.   stackoverflow is for questions regarding 'it does not compile/link' and 'it does not output the expected outputs'.   So this question is off topic and should be closed

Comment: This question is being discussed on meta [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307595/what-should-i-do-with-this-history-question)

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pascal had enumerated types, but didn't use the keyword `enum`. AFAIK, the keyword `enum` was first used by C, but the concept is older by quite a margin.

See Wikipedia on [Enumerated type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type) for an example such as:

```pascal
type
  cardsuit = (clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades);
  card = record
           suit: cardsuit;
           value: 1 .. 13;
         end;
var
  hand: array [ 1 .. 13 ] of card; 
  trump: cardsuit;
```

I think Pascal is the oldest of the languages listed on the Wikipedia page.  The LISP referred to is Common Lisp, which postdates Pascal even though original LISP handily pre-dates Pascal.

[The Programming Language Pascal](http://www.standardpascal.org/The_Programming_Language_Pascal_1970.pdf) from 1970 lists these types in section 6.1.1 Scalar Types, so for all practical purposes, these enumerated types have always been a part of Pascal.  See the [documents](http://www.standardpascal.org/documents.html) page at the [Standard Pascal](http://www.standardpascal.org/) web site.  The revised report is also available there (1972), and is probably the more widely read document.  You can also track [Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29) at Wikipedia, of course.

*(There might be another earlier language with analogous features; I've not identified it, but I've not looked everywhere.  Algol-60 was not such a language, though; nor was Fortran or Cobol.  Algol-68 and PL/1 are possible contenders.)*

Answer (score 2):

Algol 68 did not have enums.  PL/I did not have enums.
Historic Lisp had no notion of compile-time types at all.
Algol W and Simula 67 did not have enums.  Oddly enough,
COBOL is not only a possible contender but the most likely
one.  Not that it had user-definable types, but look up
"88-level".  The macro facilities of Burroughs Algol,
SAIL, CORAL 66, and RTL/2 could be used to give names to numbers,
which takes you almost as far as C's rather broken enums go.

Comment: Algol68 has "tagged-unions" where there is a similar compile time generation of **typed** `enums`, for example the following "case" statement is interrogating the "tag" ... `CASE f IN
      (APPLE):"Apple",
      (BANANA):"Banana",
      (CHERRY):"Cherry"
    OUT
      "?" # uninitalised #
    ESAC;` ... This code example is from [RosettaCode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Enumerations#ALGOL_68)